# sh is not a function in react after switch from zsh, then back to bash

Tags: reactjs, bash, zsh

in mac, I switch from bash to zsh, then zsh back to bash

chsh -s zsh

switch back to bash

```
'use strict'

const sh = require('shell-exec')

module.exports = function (port, method = 'tcp') {
  port = Number.parseInt(port)

  if (!port) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('Invalid argument provided for port'))
  }

  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    return sh(
      `Stop-Process -Id (Get-Net${method === 'UDP' ? 'UDP' : 'TCP'}Connection -LocalPort ${port}).OwningProcess -Force`
    )
  }

  return sh(
    `lsof -i ${method === 'udp' ? 'udp' : 'tcp'}:${port} | grep ${method === 'udp' ? 'UDP' : 'LISTEN'} | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`
  )
}


TypeError: sh is not a function
```

update 1:

https://github.com/tiaanduplessis/shell-exec/blob/master/src/index.ts

```
import * as childProcess from "child_process";

type Command = string | string[];

interface CmdResult {
  code?: number | null;
  stdout: string;
  stderr: string;
  error?: Error;
  cmd: string;
}

export interface FailedExec extends CmdResult {
  error: Error;
}
export interface SuccessfulExec extends CmdResult {
  code: number | null;
}

function shellExec(
  cmd: Command,
  opts?: Omit<childProcess.SpawnOptionsWithoutStdio, "stdio" | "cwd">
): Promise<CmdResult> {
  const executable = Array.isArray(cmd) ? cmd.join(";") : cmd;
  const options: childProcess.SpawnOptionsWithoutStdio = {
    ...opts,
    stdio: "pipe",
    cwd: process.cwd(),
  };

  const { platform } = process;

  try {
    const cmd = platform === "win32" ? "cmd" : "sh";
    const arg = platform === "win32" ? "/C" : "-c";
    const child = childProcess.spawn(cmd, [arg, executable], options);

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const stdoutList: string[] = [];
      const stderrList: string[] = [];

      if (child.stdout) {
        child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
          if (Buffer.isBuffer(data)) return stdoutList.push(data.toString());
          stdoutList.push(data);
        });
      }

      if (child.stderr) {
        child.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
          if (Buffer.isBuffer(data)) return stderrList.push(data.toString());
          stderrList.push(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
      }

      const getDefaultResult = () => {
        const stderr = stderrList.join("\n");
        const stdout = stdoutList.join("\n");
        return { stdout, stderr, cmd: executable };
      };

      child.on("error", (error) => resolve({ ...getDefaultResult(), error }));
      child.on("close", (code) => resolve({ ...getDefaultResult(), code }));
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
}

export default shellExec;
```

In my react project, shell-exec looks like not exist?

Comment: Did you try to open a new terminal session?

Comment: you mean it used to work before you "switch from zsh, then back to bash"?

Comment: no idea why that makes a diff since the code is in js. you better check what `sh` actually is after `const sh = require('shell-exec')`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. As a workaround, try :

```
const sh = require('shell-exec').default
```